# How to toggle multiple master windows orientation

Tags: xmonad

I'm using the following [XMonad.Layout.ThreeColumns](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.17.0/docs/XMonad-Layout-ThreeColumns.html) layout

```
-----------------------------------
|        |               |        |    
|        |               |        |
|        |               |        |
|--------|     Master    |--------|  
|        |               |        |  
|        |               |        | 
|        |               |        |
-----------------------------------
```

when I use `sendMessage (IncMaster 1)` via hotkey it splits Master window horizontally

```
-----------------------------------
|        |               |        |    
|        |    Master 1   |        |
|        |               |        |
|--------|---------------|--------|  
|        |               |        |  
|        |    Master 2   |        | 
|        |               |        |
-----------------------------------
```

How to split it vertically or toggle it to vertical orientation?
To make it like this:

```
-------------------------------------
|        |        |        |        |    
|        |        |        |        |
|        |        |        |        |
|--------|Master 1|Master 2|--------|  
|        |        |        |        |
|        |        |        |        |
|        |        |        |        |
-------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by forking Layout and hard coding it to split vertically:

```
mkdir -p ~/.xmonad/lib/XMonad/Layout
wget "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xmonad/xmonad-contrib/master/XMonad/Layout/ThreeColumns.hs" -o ~/.xmonad/lib/XMonad/Layout/My.hs
```

Change module name:

```
module XMonad.Layout.My
```

Fix importing `XMonad.Prelude` module problems:

```
-- import XMonad.Prelude
import Control.Monad (ap, msum)
```

Change behavior from this:

```
tile3 middle f r nmaster n
    | n <= nmaster || nmaster == 0 = splitVertically n r
    | n <= nmaster+1 = splitVertically nmaster s1 ++ splitVertically (n-nmaster) s2
    | otherwise = splitVertically nmaster r1 ++ splitVertically nslave1 r2 ++ splitVertically nslave2 r3
```

to this:

```
tile3 middle f r nmaster n
    | n <= nmaster || nmaster == 0 = splitHorizontally n r
    | n <= nmaster+1 = splitVertically nmaster s1 ++ splitVertically (n-nmaster) s2
    | otherwise = splitHorizontally nmaster r1 ++ splitVertically nslave1 r2 ++ splitVertically nslave2 r3
```

~/.xmonad/xmonad.hs:

```
--import XMonad.Layout.ThreeColumns
import XMonad.Layout.My
```